# открытие окна по кнопке JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Я как бы новичок в программировании, и у меня возник такой вопрос. Как правильней открыть новое окно по кнопке используя javaFX? У меня есть первоначальное оформление окна в **sample.fxml**, в классе **Main** я его запускаю, по определенной кнопке из **sample** у меня должно открыться второе окно (из другого fxml файла), так вот как это правильно реализовать?

Как я понимаю мне надо в контроллере написать обработчик событий на открытие окна по нажатию нужной кнопки, и уже в **sample** задать этой кнопке метод открытия нового окна, это правильный подход? или какая логика при подобных задачах?

Спасибо.

Comment: Правильный. В методе обработки клика загружаете `xml` файл. Далее в модалке открываете или же в основном `primaryStage` заменяете вьюху.

Comment: @Tsyklop объясните пожалуйста, что за "вьюха"? я так понял это типа мое окно. Так же не очень понятен термин модалка, и primaryStage это что метод? Или что это?

Comment: `primaryStage` это основное окно которое вы получаете при запуске приложения в методе `start` (если не ошибаюсь). Модальное окно - окно которое открывается поверх основного. "вьюха" - от англ view или отображение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы добавить событие, срабатывающее по нажатию кнопки, в fxml добавьте параметр для кнопки `onAction="#openNewStage"` (окно - это `stage`, содержимое окна - `scene`), далее IDE подсветит Вам красным и предложит самой сделать его в java файле (если в fxml вы указали контроллер конечно). 
Далее в этом методе вам нужен код идентичный тому, что был в методе start, которым вы отобразили основное окно, за одним исключением, там primaryStage передавался готовый, тут его нужно будет создать `Stage newStage = new Stage()`.

Немного забегая вперед, при клике на кнопку будет каждый раз вызываться `fxmlLoader.load()` - это не самая быстрая команда, попробуйте сделать код так, что бы она вызывалась только один раз, а потом использовался ее результат полученный ранее.

Comment: сделал примерно как Вы написали, и вроде бы все хорошо и понятно и должно работать, но Java заставляет меня написать исключение (**Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException**), и ссылается на строку 
`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("chat.fxml"));`, хотя в классе **Main** исключения не создавалось, не подскажите почему так?

Comment: Ну у вас обращение к файловой системе, отсюда `IOException`, ведь этого файла может не оказаться. У `start()` метод, который переопределяете `public abstract void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception`, наверное у вас тоже есть `throws Exception`